# filter keys which has a value containing "testing" and update using yq

Tags: yq

I have the below code which I'm looking to find the keys containing `testing` and update the value of `CloudProvider` to `x` using `yq`. Please help me.

```
List1:
  - List2:
      - team: dba
        CloudProvider: aws
        Comment: testing
      - team: it
        CloudProvider: aws
        Comment: staging
      - team: qa
        CloudProvider: azure
        Comment: testing
      - team: qa
        CloudProvider: azure
        Comment: testing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just traverse to the desired location, and wrap the traversal into parentheses to make it one entity for the assignment, so the overall structure won't change because the context isn't altered outside the parens:

```bash
(.List1[].List2[] | select(.Comment == "testing")).CloudProvider = "x"
```

```yaml
List1:
  - List2:
      - team: dba
        CloudProvider: x
        Comment: testing
      - team: it
        CloudProvider: aws
        Comment: staging
      - team: qa
        CloudProvider: x
        Comment: testing
      - team: qa
        CloudProvider: x
        Comment: testing
```

Works with [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq/) and [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) alike.

Comment: thank you very much it worked as required. I even tried with wildcard character (`*`) and that too worked.

Comment: Note that selecting by wildcards only works with [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/), not with [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq/). But both implementations can make use of regular expressions.